# Why is b3 a blunder?

Tags: learning, blunder, attack, closed-position

```
[FEN "r2q2nr/p3kppp/3bp3/2p2b2/Bn1P4/1P2PN2/4NPPP/R1BQ1RK1 b - - 0 13"]
```

I dont see whats wrong in b3 I am making some space to bring black bishop into game attacking nb4

Comment: One thing to note with the b3 move is that it breaks the communication between the white a4 bishop and the c2 square. So if you're planning to play Ba3 to attack black's knight in the coming moves black will be able to respond with Nc2 without dropping the knight. I'm not sure exactly how bad the move is, how large is the drop in evaluation according to the engine?

Comment: Its about 2 pawns went from 3 to 1

Comment: I see, that's reasonable. As was pointed out in the answer below, part of white's advantage lies in the fact that black's king is unsafe which means that it's good to be as efficient as possible to inflict as much damage as possible before the opponent manages to get their king to safety. Also, it's worth pointing out that computers and humans tend to disagree as to what should be called a blunder at times; the computer only uses the evaluation drop to distinguish between moves, while humans tend to try to see whether a move 'makes sense' in some regard in order to evaluate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a blunder, as White still has a large advantage after 1.b3. But more efficient is 1.dxc5 Bxc5 2.Bd2. Here White's attacking the knight, but has only spent one tempo developing his bishop. Your idea with 1.b3, 2.Ba3 would take two tempi.

In this kind of position where the opponent's king is vulnerable, each tempo matters more. You want to take advantage of things before the king gets to safety.